# Indexing in For Loop R

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I am coming from Python and am trying to define a For Loop with print the first 168 observations of some Data in the first iteration, in the second I want it to print observation 2 until 169 instead. That is, dropping and adding one observation for each iteration.

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(df[i:167+i])
}
```

This is the code I am trying to run. What this code does is:
First iteration: Print thje first 168 observation.
Second iteration: Drop two observations from the start, and adds one in the end, so it prints observation 3-169, instead of 2-169.

If I instead run:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  print(df[i:168])
}
```

It works as I want, only dropping one observations in the beginning of the sample for each iteration.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Try in a console `1:5+1` versus `1:(5+1)`.

Comment: As an aside, since R is vectorized use of explicit loops is usually unnecessary and avoided whenever possible.  It is not clear why want to print individual rows of your dataframe.  E.g. at the console `mtcars(2:10, ]` will print rows 2:10 to the console.  No `for` loop required.